# Mysql error converting to date time

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble converting time to date time with this mysql query:

```
UPDATE profiles SET datetime = str_to_date(olddate, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s');
olddate format is: 1/01/2012 0:00
datetime format is 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I've tried dropping the seconds but with the same error:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '1/01/2012 0:00' for function str_to_date
```

Comment: what kind of datatype is datetime and olddate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will give MySQL formatted `datetime`

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1/01/2012 0:00','%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
+------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('1/01/2012 0:00','%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00                            |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Have a look at [**MySQL STR_TO_DATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Ah I didn't notice it when you posted but the error was that I had %h when it should have been %H for 24 hour clock